# Faced Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs

I was creating a project in React and faced the error of "
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I tried hard to fix on my own but no result thus I really need your kind help. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import styles from "./dropZone.module.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { ReactComponent as ReactLogo } from "../../assets/plan.svg";
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
import { ADD } from "../../store/actionTypes/actionTypes";
import { ReactCanvasAnnotation, LABEL_TYPE } from "react-canvas-annotation";

function DropZone(props) {
  const fileSelector = useSelector((state) => state.fileReducer.file);
  const isEditMode = useSelector((state) => state.editReducer.isEditMode);
  const [annotationType, setAnnotationType] = useState(null);
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState(null);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {
    fileRejections,
    isDragReject,
    isDragActive,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
  } = useDropzone({
    accept: "image/jpeg, image/png",
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD,
        payload: acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
          Object.assign(file, {
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
          })
        ),
      });
    },
  });

  const onConsole = (msg) => (id) => console.info(msg, id);

  const thumbs = fileSelector.map((file) => (
    <div key={file.name}>
      <img className={styles.uploadedImage} src={file.preview} />
    </div>
  ));

  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      // Make sure to revoke the data uris to avoid memory leaks
      fileSelector.forEach((file) => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
    },
    [fileSelector]
  );

  const isFileTooLarge =
    fileRejections.length > 0 && fileRejections[0].size > props.maxSize;

  return (
    <section className={styles.container}>
      {isEditMode && (
        <>
          <TransformWrapper>
            {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, ...rest }) => (
              <>
                <Button
                  className={styles.zoomIn}
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={zoomIn}
                >
                  Zoom in
                </Button>
                <Button
                  className={styles.zoomOut}
                  variant="contained"
                  color="secondary"
                  onClick={zoomOut}
                >
                  Zoom out
                </Button>
                <Button
                  className={styles.reset}
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={resetTransform}
                >
                  x
                </Button>

                <TransformComponent>
                  <div {...getRootProps({ className: styles.dropZone })}>
                    {fileSelector.length > 0 && <div>{thumbs}</div>}
                  </div>
                </TransformComponent>
              </>
            )}
          </TransformWrapper>
        </>
      )}

      {fileSelector.length > 0 && !isEditMode && (
        <>
          <ReactCanvasAnnotation
            imageFile={thumbs}
            labels={labels}
            onChange={setLabels}
            annotationType={annotationType}
            onMouseOut={onConsole(`onMouseOut`)}
            onHover={onConsole(`onHover`)}
            onClick={onConsole(`onClick`)}
          />

          <div {...getRootProps({ className: styles.dropZone })}>
            {fileSelector.length > 0 && <div>{thumbs}</div>}
          </div>
        </>
      )}

      {fileSelector.length === 0 && (
        <div {...getRootProps({ className: styles.dropZone })}>
          {fileSelector.length === 0 && !isEditMode && (
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
          )}
          {fileSelector.length === 0 && (
            <div>
              <span>{isDragActive ? <ReactLogo /> : <ReactLogo />}</span>
              <h3>Click Yellow zone or drop an image to upload!</h3>
            </div>
          )}
          {isDragReject && <h3>This file type not supported, sorry!</h3>}
          {isDragActive && !isDragReject && <h3>Drop it AS IF it's hot!</h3>}
          {isFileTooLarge && <div>File is too large.</div>}
          {fileRejections.length > 0 && "File not supported"}
        </div>
      )}
    </section>
  );
}

export default DropZone;
```

Comment: @DennisVash, hey Dennis, can you help I just was using your package react canvas annotation and I think <<ReactCanvasAnnotation/> causes that issue since if I remove it all works ok

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any overt issues with the hooks you use in this functional component, so maybe it is coming from a component downstream.

Comment: @DrewReese, is it possible that the issue is happening due to discrepancy in react versions, that is, I have one version of react and package has a different version?

Comment: Perhaps, but I think that would be more likely a scenario where react v^16.8.4 is listed as a peer dependency (for hooks) and the system consuming the 3rd party module isn't up-to-date. But you don't seem to be seeing any errors for *your* hook usage. Another alternative is #3 where the `react-canvas-annotation` is exporting "built" components that are using the other instance of react.

Comment: @DrewReese, sorry Drew, the author of the package is lost :D but since I really need to create a project very like to react-canvas-annotation, is there any other packages that can help me achieve that? Maybe you know, I am googling but cannot find the appropriate one

Comment: Oof, what version of react is *your* project running, they have react ^16.13.1 listed as a peer dependency, which is the current latest react release version. https://github.com/denvash/react-canvas-annotation/blob/master/package.json#L26-L28

Comment: @DrewReese, I am also using react: ^16.13.1

Comment: @DennisVash, Dennis, I have created an issue here pls help https://github.com/denvash/react-canvas-annotation/issues/2

Comment: @user13647380 did you resolve this? I've just seen this same bug in a react code demo for react-zoom-pan-pinch and also on my own implementation .